# perl: index query containing unspecified characters

Tags: perl, indexing, match

I want to find the position of all matches using the index function in perl. The tricky part is that my query has variable letters inside (I use a simple example here).

```
my $query="b\wll"; 
my $string= "I see a ball on a bull";

my $output = index($string, $query, $offset); 
while ($output != -1) {

        print "$char\t$output\n";
```

the output I want is

```
ball  8
bull  18
```

It should look something like this but I can't get it to work. Could you please help ?

Comment: Do you want to count overlapping matches? For example, if the string is `aaa` and the query is `aa`, would you return two matches (indexes 0 and 1) or just one match (index 0)?

Comment: Please *always* `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the start of *every* Perl program you write, especially before asking for help with it. This measure would have pointed you straight to the answer to your question

Answer (score 3):

`\w` isn't defined in double-quoted string literals.

```
$ perl -wE'say "b\wll";'
Unrecognized escape \w passed through at -e line 1.
bwll
```

To create the string `b\wll`, you need

```
"b\\wll"
```

In this case, you could also use the following since you are creating a regex pattern:

```
qr/b\wll/
```

So that solves the first problem, but there's second: [`index`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html) doesn't know anything about regular expressions. You need to use the match operator for that.

```
my $pattern = "b\\wll"; 
my $string = "I see a ball on a bull";

while ($string =~ /($pattern)/g) {
   print "$-[1]\t$1\n";
}
```

When using the match operator in scalar context, we can see where each match matched using [`@-`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%40-).

Comment: See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%40LAST_MATCH_START for the use of the magic `@-` variable here.

Comment: @glenn jackman, Thanks, I was just about to add that, and I now have.

Answer (score 0):

Find all matches, and the text that came before, then add up the string lengths:

```
perl -E '
  my $query = q{b\wll};
  my $string = qq{I see a ball on a bull};
  my @matches = $string =~ /(.*?)($query)/g;
  $, = qq{\t};
  for (my ($pos, $i) = (0,0); $i < @matches; $i+=2) {
    $pos += length $matches[$i];
    say $matches[$i+1], $pos;
    $pos += length $matches[$i+1];
  }
'
```

```
ball    8
bull    18
```